# Converting Personal Messaging code from MYSQL into MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, messaging

I am trying to build a personal messaging system into my project. I have been using MYSQLi so far in the project, I just found this code for PMS. Now I don't know how to convert this mysql code into mysqli..

```
<?php    
session_start();

$message = $_POST['forward2'];
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// if the form has been submitted, this inserts it into the Database 
  $to_user = $_POST['to_user'];
  $from_user = $_POST['from_user'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (to_user, message, from_user) VALUES ('$to_user', '$message', '$from_user')")or die(mysql_error());
  echo "PM succesfully sent!"; 
}
else
{
    // if the form has not been submitted, this will show the form
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr><td colspan=2><h3>Send PM:</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
<input type="hidden" name="from_user" maxlength="32" value = <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>To User: </td><td>
<input type="text" name="to_user" maxlength="32" value = "">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Message: </td><td>
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" COLS=50 ROWS=10 WRAP=SOFT></TEXTAREA>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you not simply tried `mysqli_query` (mysqli_)?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysqli-procedural-functions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get yourself a tutorial on mysqli.
2. Follow it through.
3. Create some simple mysqli-based application.
4. Make yourself familiar with mysqli
5. Then start with transition.